# Ubuntu 10.04 keep disconnecting idle ssh connections after few minutes?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I just installed a new Ubuntu Server 10.04 and I observed that if I do not use my connection for a while it will just disconnect me.

This never happened to me on CentOS or even on older Ubuntu.

/var/log/auth does not contain any hints regarding the disconnections.

Inside /etc/ssh/sshd there is line with `TCPKeepAlive yes`. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/157080/ubuntu-10-04-keep-disconnecting-idle-ssh-connections-after-few-minutes/157085#157085), just add the following to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UseDNS no
```

Answer (score 0):

please edit you sshd config:

nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

search for "ClientAliveInterval"

change it to 0

reload sshd

/etc/init.d/ssh restart

Comment: Sorry, your proposed solution did not solved my problem but strangely I see this in auth log:  reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for user-x.y.z.w.domain.com [x.y.z.w] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!. The timing of these messages seams to match the connection droppings. I do not remember to see sshd closing connection when reverse was failing. WTF?